# How is Qisas done when equal retaliation is not possible?

Tags: diyya, qisas

For example, suppose that a tooth-less person breaks the teeth of another, or an eye-less person pokes out another's eye, or a woman cuts off a man's penis, or a man cuts off a woman's breasts etc. Like-for-like retaliation is not possible, so what happens if the victim demands Qisas?

My guess is that substitutions are defined or the victim has to settle for monetary compensation only.

Comment: For comparison, I think in Jewish law eye-for-an-eye is interpreted to merit only monetary compensation in such cases.